# save selected checkbox and radio button in notepad

Tags: java, checkbox

I need to save information for my final project and need one little thing to complete it.

**My Question is:** *How do I save a selected checkbox or radio button in notepad?*

I know how to save any string-based information, but I don't know how to save the selected checkbox/radio button to my notepad - so, as I open it back and it will select it automatically. I tried `if(chkE.isSelected() == true)`, but I don't know what to write to make it save into my notepad.

Thank you in advance!

**Here is my code:**

```
try {
     JFileChooser flcFile = new JFileChooser("c:/");
     int rep = flcFile.showSaveDialog(this);
     File filesave = flcFile.getSelectedFile();
     if (rep == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
         try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filesave)) {
              //if(chkE.isSelected() == true){
                  //do stuff
              //}

              writer.write(String.valueOf(txtNom1.getText()));
              writer.write("\r\n");
              writer.write(String.valueOf(txtPre1.getText()));
              writer.write("\r\n");
              writer.write(String.valueOf(optoui.getText()));
              writer.write("\r\n");
              writer.write(String.valueOf(optoui.getText()));
              writer.write("\r\n");
              writer.write(String.valueOf(optnon.getText()));
              writer.write("\r\n");
              writer.write(String.valueOf(chkanimaux.getText()));
              writer.write("\r\n");
              writer.write(String.valueOf(chkChauffer.getText()));
              writer.write("\r\n");
              writer.write(String.valueOf(chkE.getText()));
              writer.write("\r\n"); 
              writer.write(String.valueOf(txttel.getText()));
              writer.write("\r\n");

              writer.close();
         }
     }    
} catch(IOException err1) {

}
```

---

*English isn't my native language.*

Comment: you can save 1 for checked and 0 for unchecked in your file.

Comment: Notepad is a text editor and so it *only* accepts text. Btw. what does the code have to do with your environment?

Comment: @Jimmy ``true``/``false`` is very common, too.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman true that.

Comment: my code is to save name, checkbox or radiotbutton into notepad or somethingelse and when ill open it, it will put name back into my text field and it will select my checkbox/radiobutton

Comment: Please define "save checkbox/radiobutton into notepad"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell what you really want to do from your question. As I understand it, you have a dialog with different input elements that you want to save and then reload.

Since the value of a checkbox is a boolean value, just store the String representation of that value like this:

```
writer.write(String.valueOf(chkE.isSelected()));
```

When reading back, you convert the text by using

```
chkE.setSelected(Boolean.valueOf(text));
```

However, you should add some error handling code.

Comment: it did selected when i load it back ty guys